# TF-Lite Non-Max-Suppression

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am attempting to convert a graph with tf.image.non_max_suppression or tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression but both API calls yield an error like "tf.CombinedNonMaxSuppression op is neither a custom op nor a flex op." My setup is TF2.3.1, python 3.7, Windows 10.

I understand that some tf functions are not supported for conversion to TF-Lite but the link below shows tfl function for non-max-suppression.

https://tensorflow.google.cn/mlir/tfl_ops#tflnon_max_suppression_v4_tflnonmaxsuppressionv4op

What do I need to do to be able to run the converter on my function in order to use the tfl.non_max_suppression_vx function?

Answer (score 1):

Non-max-suppression operation is not supported in TF Lite. If you want to use them you have to use via TF lib, when converting, adding these lines

```
converter.experimental_new_converter=True

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                                   tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
```

There is an other way that you should rewrite NMS op by ops supported in TF Lite or sort of so. If you rewrite successfully, please tell me. Thanks.